# unit of work - I don't need to use transactions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

If I use Microsoft implementation unit of work from this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
    private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
    private GenericRepository<Course> courseRepository;

    public GenericRepository<Department> DepartmentRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.departmentRepository == null)
            {
                this.departmentRepository = new GenericRepository<Department>(context);
            }
            return departmentRepository;
        }
    }

    public GenericRepository<Course> CourseRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.courseRepository == null)
            {
                this.courseRepository = new GenericRepository<Course>(context);
            }
            return courseRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    //......
}
```

I don't need to use transactions when I must add related items? For example when I must add order and order positions to database I don't need to start transaction because if something will go wrong then method Save() won't execute yes? Am I right?

```
_unitOfWork.OrdersRepository.Insert(order);
_unitOfWork.OrderPositionsRepository.Insert(orderPosition);
_unitOfWork.Save();
```

??

Answer (score 2):

`SaveChanges` itself is transactional. Nothing happens at the database level when you call `Insert`, which based on the tutorial merely calls `Add` on the `DbSet`. Only once `SaveChanges` is called on the context does the database get hit and everything that happened up to that point is sent in one transaction.

Comment: So is it possible that order insert in database without order positions or not?

Comment: Entity Framework takes care of this. It knows that it needs to save the related class before it can save the classes with foreign keys to that.

Answer (score 2):

You need transactions if you have multiple save changes in one method ... or chain of method calls using the same context.

Then you can roll back over the multiple save changes when your final update fails.

An example would be multiple repositories wrapping crud for an entity under the unit of work (IE a generic class). You may have many functions inserting and saving in each repository. However at the end you may find an issue which causes you to roll back previous saves.

EG in a service layer that needs to hit many repositories and execute a complex operation.

Comment: thx You very much -now I understand when I must use transaction